# Ruby's ARGV can be empty on windows depending on a way to run script

Tags: ruby, argv

My demo.rb:

```
puts ARGV.size

ARGV.each do |a|
  puts "Argument: #{a}"
end
```

The result depends on how we run a script:

```
> demo.rb foo bar
0

> ruby demo.rb foo bar
2
Argument: foo
Argument: bar
```

Why this happens? And can some thing be done with this?

**EDIT:** 
  Thanks to all replies! Here my settings:

```
>assoc .rb
.rb=rbFile

>ftype rbFile
rbFile="c:\ruby-1.8.6\bin\ruby.exe" "%1" %*
```

So it looks right.

But I have discovered that

```
>demo.rb foo bar
```

starts process with such Command Line:

```
"C:\ruby-1.8.7\bin\ruby.exe" "c:\demo.rb"
```

Notice, that .rb associated with 1.8.6, but 1.8.7 is started.

So I guess some thing else is messed up?

Answer (score 8):

Open a command window:

```
assoc .rb
```

is it rbFile?

```
ftype rbFile
```

Make sure that Ruby.exe is followed by "%1" %*

the %* is sometimes missing.

Answer (score 3):

```
C:\Temp> ftype | grep ruby
rbFile="c:\opt\ruby\bin\ruby.exe" "%1" %*
rbwFile="c:\opt\ruby\bin\rubyw.exe" "%1" %*
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the file association. Especially in the advanced settings look at the "Open" action. Make sure that there is a %* on the end of the action.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303921/passing-around-command-line-args-in-powershell-from-function-to-function) question is about powershell, but it is essentially the same question so my answer there should give a little more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the arguments are not passed on to the ruby interpreter, in your association of the filetype. See [this section](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Simple_Ruby_Examples#Associating_Ruby_Files_on_Windows) for how the association should look, and verify yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a freeware tool from [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) - [FileTypesManager](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) - to add the missing `%*` as mentioned in the other posts.